# How can I skip over the last line of a function in pdb?

Tags: python, pdb

Using the python debugger pdb is it possible to skip the last line of a function such that it is not executed, and if so how? While the debugger is paused at the last line of the function, I've tried using `jump <current line + 1>` (e.g. current line is 122 and I type `jump 123`) but this gives an error:

```
*** Jump failed: line 123 comes after the current code block
```

(Note I can jump over other lines of code it's just the last line of a function that my question is about)

Comment: same here...the only workaround I found is to comment the line

Comment: ( or something similar, like adding 'return None)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what I need, and it hasn't been answered in 3 years... Maybe there really is no way. As a workaround, you can try to make the last line effect-less and then run it, e.g. if the last line is `self.foo()`, you can set `self.foo = lambda: None` (And hopefully remember to undo it later..)